# Duplicate Data from two column

Tags: mysql, database-design, php, unique-constraint

i have a table which has only two column one is pid(Photo ID) and another one is tid(Tag ID)

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pid   | int(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| tid   | int(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

this table will store a photo id with a tag id, but i am facing a problem and i guess which is against normalization as well, here is my table data.

```
+-----+-----+
| pid | tid |
+-----+-----+
|  10 |   1 |
|  10 |   2 |
|  10 |   3 |
|  10 |   4 |
|   0 |   6 |
|   0 |  10 |
|   0 |  10 |
|  10 |   1 |
|  10 |   2 |
|  10 |   3 |
|  10 |   4 |
+-----+-----+
```

it store many duplicate values, how to get rid of this?
I mean, how i can store this types of row only for one time: `|  10 |   1 |` 
I have tried with `UNIQE` but this will going to store a photo id or a tag id only for one time?
I'm using PHP
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a compound unique index.

Suppose your table is called `photos`. You can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE photos_new LIKE photos;
ALTER TABLE photos_new ADD UNIQUE INDEX pid_tid_index (pid,tid);
INSERT IGNORE INTO photos_new SELECT * FROM photos;
ALTER TABLE photos RENAME photos_old;
ALTER TABLE photos_new RENAME photos;
```

If it works out, then run

```
DROP TABLE photos_old;
```

Give it a Try !!!